# Authorization Header is not being sent in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I Have configured HttpInterceptor with Authorization Header Token and I'm trying handle http error. But Authorization header is not being sent. Before Adding Error Handler it was working fine.Also I have registered my interceptor in AppModule.

//My interceptor.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler,
    HttpRequest,HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError} from "rxjs/internal/operators";
import {ToastrService} from "ngx-toastr";

@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private toastService : ToastrService)
    {

    }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let reqHeader;
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('token')!==null || sessionStorage.getItem('token')!==undefined)
            reqHeader = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization',
            sessionStorage.getItem('token'))});
        else
        reqHeader = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', "123")});


        return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError((error, caught) => {
            console.log(error);
            this.handleAuthError(error);
            return of(error);
        }) as any);

    }


    /**
    * manage errors
    * @param err
    * @returns {any}
    */
    private handleAuthError(err: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
        //handle your auth error or rethrow

        console.log(err);
        this.toastService.error("Error Received","Err");
        throw err;
    }

}
```

// My App Module.ts

```
providers: [{
provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
useClass: MyInterceptor,
multi: true,
}
```

Comment: You have to change `!=null` to `!==null` and `!=undefine` to `!==undefined` first.

Comment: updated. Not working.

Comment: change ``next.handle(req) `` to ``next.handle(reqHeader)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have refactor your code, you were not throwing error in right way, take a look in code.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
    import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class IntercepterHttp implements HttpInterceptor {
        constructor(
        ) { }

        intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            let reqHeader;
            if(sessionStorage.getItem('token')!=null || sessionStorage.getItem('token')!=undefined)
            reqHeader = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 
        sessionStorage.getItem('token'))});
    else
        reqHeader = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', "123")});

            return next.handle(reqHeader).pipe(
                catchError(response => {
                    if (response instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                        return throwError(response);
                    }
                })
            )
        }
    }
```